# CloudFormation refusing to create AWS::KMS::Key with least privilege

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kms, least-privilege

Endeavouring to apply the principle of least privilege to a CMK I'm creating, the goal is to create a CloudFormation template that can be used via StackSets to the entire organisation. As a result, I want a key that can be used (`kms:Encrypt`, `kms:Decrypt` etc.) for general encryption tasks in the account, but that cannot be modified by principals in the account (specifically `kms:PutKeyPolicy` but not only).

I have a working policy lifted from a hand crafted key. The CloudFormation template works fine, the StackSet initiates the resource creation.

But *only* when I don't restrict the account principal with any conditions, which removes the least privilege principle. The [`CreateKey`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_CreateKey.html#KMS-CreateKey-request-BypassPolicyLockoutSafetyCheck) and [`PutKeyPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_PutKeyPolicy.html#KMS-PutKeyPolicy-request-BypassPolicyLockoutSafetyCheck) API calls both have an option `BypassPolicyLockoutSafetyCheck` for those of us idiotic enough to think they know better! Except CloudFormation doesn't expose that for [`AWS::KMS::Key`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kms-key.html) :(

So unless I basically leave the key policy wide open, I get the following error in the Stack:

> Resource handler returned message: "The new key policy will not allow you to update the key policy in the future. (Service: Kms, Status Code: 400, Request ID: xxxx, Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: xxxx, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

I've tried a variety of options for the principal, with the `Condition` *removed* (as below) the key is created, with it *in* no joy.

```
- Sid: AllowUpdatesByCloudFormation
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            AWS: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root"
          Action:
          - kms:Describe*
          - kms:List*
          - kms:PutKeyPolicy
          - kms:CreateAlias
          - kms:UpdateAlias
          - kms:UpdateKeyDescription
          - kms:EnableKey
          - kms:DisableKey
          - kms:EnableKeyRotation
          - kms:DisableKeyRotation
          - kms:GetKey*
          - kms:DeleteAlias
          - kms:TagResource
          - kms:UntagResource
          - kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion
          - kms:CancelKeyDeletion
          Resource: '*'
          # Condition:
          #   StringEquals:
          #     "aws:PrincipalAccount": !Sub ${AWS::AccountId}
          #     "kms:ViaService": !Sub "cloudformation.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com"
```

I've tried with different principal settings, including `AWS: "*"` and a few different `Service` options, and different settings on the `Condition`. I've tried with and without the region in the service name. I must be missing something, but I've lost a few hours scratching my head over this one.

Web searches, AWS forum searches have turned up nothing, so I'm hoping the good bhurgers of StackOverflow can guide me - and future me's searching for the same help :)

It doesn't seem possible to link to the table section on the AWS KMS API page for the condition keys on [`CreateKey` or `PutKeyPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/kms-api-permissions-reference.html#kms-api-permissions-reference-table) but I don't think I've missed a trick with those?

Thanks in advance - Robert.

Answer (score 3):

Try giving the root user all kms permissions - (kms:*)
The principle of least privilege still applies when giving root all access.

That will enable IAM User permissions.

Add additional policies to each role or user or user group.
Add a policy for key administration.
Add a policy for usage.
That is where you can fine tune your access.

Try working with this key policy and tweak it.
This is a key I use for RDS encryption in a cfn stack.
(Yes!  I know that policies should be applied to user groups, not users directly for best practices... but this is inside a sandbox environment I have access to from 'aCloud guru')

```
  KeyPolicy:
    Id: key-consolepolicy-3
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
      - Sid: Enable IAM User Permissions
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          AWS: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root"
        Action: kms:*
        Resource: '*'
      - Sid: Allow access for Key Administrators
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          AWS:
            - !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/admin"
            - !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/cloud_user"
        Action:
          - kms:Create*
          - kms:Describe*
          - kms:Enable*
          - kms:List*
          - kms:Put*
          - kms:Update*
          - kms:Revoke*
          - kms:Disable*
          - kms:Get*
          - kms:Delete*
          - kms:TagResource
          - kms:UntagResource
          - kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion
          - kms:CancelKeyDeletion
        Resource: '*'
      - Sid: Allow use of the key
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          AWS: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/aws-service-role/rds.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForRDS"
        Action:
          - kms:Encrypt
          - kms:Decrypt
          - kms:ReEncrypt*
          - kms:GenerateDataKey*
          - kms:DescribeKey
        Resource: '*'
      - Sid: Allow attachment of persistent resources
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          AWS: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/aws-service-role/rds.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForRDS"
        Action:
          - kms:CreateGrant
          - kms:ListGrants
          - kms:RevokeGrant
        Resource: '*'
        Condition:
          Bool:
            kms:GrantIsForAWSResource: "true"
```

Comment: Thanks @not-a-coderp your policy is essentially what I've got, I must apologise, I only included the snippet I wanted to use specifically for CloudFormation itself. There are only roles, no users at all in this environment, the policy I have is well aligned, except for this one niggle with CloudFormation and it wanting to be able to update itself, and not granting me access to the bypass.